# How do you extract prop types from a React Component with defaultProps?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Exporting Props from a React.Component is easy enough, but how do you properly extract the types the Component is actually using, once `defaultProps` are taken into account? I imagine you could omit keys from Props and then merge with a Partial of defaultProps, but are there any built-in ways of this? Flow accomplishes this with `React.ElementConfig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<typeof MyComponent, MyComponent["props"]>
```